# Sunroom - detached vs attached

Tags: ledger, sunroom

we have been talking about building a extension room on the concrete patio. Watched some online videos and all involving attaching a ledger board to the house. However that looks very difficult regarding the water proofing job, for an amateur.

For our situation please see the attached photo, there is an over-hang with a gutter at the end. It's 120 inches above the concrete patio.

My question is, is it OK to use posts instead of a ledger board, for the house-side support? In that way we don't worry about properly removing siding boards and waterproofing.
[image]

Comment: You haven't really told us enough here. Is this thing going to be completely isolated? No roof connection? No flooring connection? More information seems necessary. It does seem like you're considering avoiding a ledger for bad reasons, though.

Comment: That said, you can't attach to your home anyway without proper footings. A patio isn't proper footings, so you'd _have_ to leave it detached.

Comment: @isherwood We hope to have roof connection between the house and the sunroom. For flooring we may just use the patio or lay wood or tile on it. Thank you for the suggestion.